# Select a radio button in all rows from a button click GTK+ python, PyGObject

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I have a an form with two boxes. The upper box and the down box. In the upper box I have two buttons. One button is Add Row and the button is Select Radio button A in all rows in the list box.

In the down box I have a Listbox with a multiple rows. All rows are similar, There are two radio buttons, A and B,  in each row. When ever you click on the Select Radio button, The A radio button on all rows should be selected.

How do I do that?

I don't want to show my code here because of copyright issues. but I believe there should be some method stating :

```
def on_button_click(self, button):
   self.Listbox.Row_all.Radio_button_A.checked()
```

I appriciate any help

UPDATE:
This is a part of my code.

```
        # Adding new row to the list

    self.row = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
    self.row.set_border_width(5)

    downBox_main = Gtk.HBox()
    downBox_main.set_halign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)

    videoIcon = Gio.ThemedIcon(name="audio-x-generic")
    videoImage = Gtk.Image.new_from_gicon(videoIcon, Gtk.IconSize.DIALOG)

    vbox_link_and_butons = Gtk.VBox()
    vbox_link_and_butons.set_border_width(5)

    link_entry = Gtk.Entry()
    link_entry.set_placeholder_text("Paste the video link here")

    quality_hbox = Gtk.HBox()

    btnsQuality = [("4320p"), ("2160p"), ("1440p"), ("1080p"), ("720p"), ("480p")]
    for buttonNames in btnsQuality:
        btn = Gtk.ToggleButton()
        btn.set_label(buttonNames)
        quality_hbox.pack_start(btn, False, False, 2)

    radiobtn_box = Gtk.VBox()
    radiobtn_box.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)

    rbVideo = Gtk.RadioButton.new_with_label_from_widget(None, "Video")
    rbAudio = Gtk.RadioButton.new_from_widget(rbVideo)
    rbAudio.set_label("Audio")

    btnDownload = Gtk.Button()
    download_icon = Gio.ThemedIcon(name="down")
    image = Gtk.Image.new_from_gicon(download_icon, Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON)
    btnDownload.add(image)

    downBox_main.pack_start(videoImage, False, False, 0)
    vbox_link_and_butons.pack_start(link_entry, True, True, 0)
    vbox_link_and_butons.pack_start(quality_hbox, True, True, 3)
    radiobtn_box.pack_start(rbVideo, False, True, 0)
    radiobtn_box.pack_start(rbAudio, False, True, 0)
    downBox_main.pack_start(vbox_link_and_butons, True, False, 8)
    downBox_main.pack_start(radiobtn_box, True, True, 0)
    downBox_main.pack_start(btnDownload, True, True, 3)
    self.row.add(downBox_main)
    self.downBox.add(self.row)
    self.downBox.show_all()
```

And I try to reach those those radio buttons in each row. There are many rows with same structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over the buttons and call each button's checked method.

Comment: I updated the question. There are two radio buttons in each row.